# Vim never shows line number for Python files even though I have `.vimrc`

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, filetype, line-numbers

I found it strange that I can never have Vim show line number automatically for `.py` files, even if I have this as my `~/.vimrc`

```
set background=dark
autocmd FileType py,c set number
```

Strangely enough, when I run `vim xxx.c` (regardless of whether `xxx.c` exists), it enables line number automatically, but never when I run `vim xxx.py`

I also tried some random extensions, but only `c` works. Like this:

```
autocmd FileType py,c,xxx,yyy,abcd,wxyz set number
```

And when I open a file with the extension written above, only `.c` file has line number automatically enabled. I tried re-ordering those extensions, but it made no difference.

---

In case they matter, here are my related settings. I've never done any modification to Vim except creating a `.vimrc` file under my home directory, after installing Vim using `sudo apt install vim`.

Output when I run `vim --version` on my Windows Subsystem for Linux:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
Included patches: 1-1689
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +tag_binary
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_old_static
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  -tag_any_white
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tcl
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     +terminfo
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +termresponse
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +textobjects
+channel         +gettext         -mzscheme        +timers
+cindent         -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clientserver    +iconv           +packages        -toolbar
-clipboard       +insert_expand   +path_extra      +user_commands
+cmdline_compl   +job             -perl            +vertsplit
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +virtualedit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +visual
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visualextra
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +viminfo
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      +python3         +wildignore
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildmenu
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +windows
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +writebackup
+diff            +menu            -ruby            -X11
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -xfontset
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xim
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xsmp
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+eval            +mouse_dec       +statusline      -xterm_save
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       -sun_workshop    -xpm
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   +syntax
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.5/config-3.5m-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.5m -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm
```

And the output for `uname -a`

```
Linux iBug-PC 4.4.0-43-Microsoft #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Extra information:

```
Non-existent environment variable: $VIM
Non-modified file: /usr/share/vim/vimrc
Non-existent directory: ~/.vim/
Non-existent file: ~/.exrc
```

Kindly tell me how to make Vim show line number for Python scripts.

Note: In this post, "Python file" means exactly any file with extension `.py`.

Comment: what is the output of `:verbose set nu?` in a python file?

Comment: FileType takes the name of the filetype (python) not an extension. Replace py with python; does that work?

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble That works. How can I apply `autocmd` to an arbitrary file extension?

Comment: Will provide detailed answer in the morning.

Comment: @iBug posted. Hope that helps.

Comment: @DavidBenKnoble Read it all. Accepted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Why it didn't work

From `:help FileType`,

```
                                      *FileType*
FileType        When the 'filetype' option has been set.  The
                pattern is matched against the filetype.
                <afile> can be used for the name of the file
                where this option was set, and <amatch> for
                the new value of 'filetype'.  Navigating to
                another window or buffer is not allowed.
                See |filetypes|.
```

The key bit there is

> The pattern is matched against the *filetype*

meaning that any `autocmd` using `FileType` should be followed by an actual filetype.

### The "solution"

```
autocmd FileType python,c set number
```

*HOWEVER* read on...

## Frame Challenge : Using Vim Properly

`autocmd` is *NOT* the solution to `filetype`-dependent settings. It might seem like a good candidate at first, but Vim was built with a philosophy of placing files in a defined directory structure to affect behavior. Most vim users learn about vimrc first. But there are more (see `:help rtp`).

What this means for the OP is as follows: Python (and C) `filetype`-dependent settings, mappings, &c. should be placed in

> `~/.vim/ftplugin/$FILETYPE.vim`

E.g., create `~/.vim/ftplugin/python.vim` with the contents

```
setlocal number
```

to have Python files get `number` on. Note I used `setlocal` to make it buffer specific.

If you find that something in these files conflicts with other settings, you should place the offending line in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim` to have it override any other settings.

Finally, make sure you at least enable filetype plugins with `filetype plugin on`.

---

In response to comments,

#### Using file extensions

To perform an `autocmd` on an arbitrary file extension, you can use any of the various `autocmd`s that match on the file name, and then use a glob (`*.ext`) as the pattern.

The two most common I see are `BufNewFile` and `BufRead` (or `BufReadPost`).

In practice, this is all of them (excepting a few special cases like `FileType`).

See `:help autocmd-events` for more.

Comment: note that with `filetype on`, vim will automatically set the filetype properly for python files.

Comment: Where do I find a list of know  `FileType`s to my installation of Vim?

Comment: check `:help :filetype` for some info, basically you can go digging *or* when you edit a file whose filetype isn't correctly detected (rare, in my exp) you create your own detecter.