# How to change indenting for html files?

Tags: neovim, indentation, filetype-html

I code mainly in 2 languages **python** and **HTML**. I currently have the indenting configured for python in my neovim configuration file but I would to know ***how to make neovim auto-detect the type of file and change the indenting script for that specific type of language***...in this case *HTML*. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Apparently I need to create a question/answer pair we can use for dupes; see [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15019/10604) or [this](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/15329/10604) for starters, and understand the tab settings (theres a [vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/tabs-and-spaces/) on it...) to set what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example from the [faq](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/vim_faq.txt.html#faq-26.1)

> You can create filetype plugins to set different options for different
>   types of files. You should first enable filetype plugins using the command:
>
> ```
>   :filetype plugin on
> ```
>
> A filetype plugin is a vim script that is loaded whenever Vim opens or
>   creates a file of that type.  For example, to ensure that the 'textwidth'
>   option is set to 80 when editing a C program (filetype 'c'), create one of
>   the following files:
>
> ```
>           ~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim (Unix)
>           %HOME%\vimfiles\ftplugin\c.vim (Windows)
> ```
>
> with the following text in it:
>
> ```
>           setlocal textwidth=80
> ```
>
> You can also use autocommands to set specific options when editing specific
>   type of files. For example, to set the 'textwidth' option to 75 for only
>   *.txt files, you can use the following autocmd:
>
> ```
>   autocmd BufRead *.txt setlocal textwidth=80
> ```

For more information, read

[:help filetype-plugin](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_43.txt.html#filetype-plugin)

[:help add-filetype-plugin](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_05.txt.html#add-filetype-plugin)